# Copy from one table to another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I know how to copy from one table to another table using MySQL:

```
INSERT INTO original_table
SELECT * FROM temp_table WHERE id = 1
```

But my situation is different:

I have `temp_table` and `original_table`. Both having same column name i.e.,

```
    id,
    state,
    city,
    address
```

But temp_table contains real name of state and city i.e, state and city column contain name of state and city. AND I want to copy this table such way that state and city should contain id of that states and city name when it move to `original_table`. There is meta table for both states and cites.

states :

```
id 
state_name
```

cities :

```
id,
state_id,
city_name
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: What does PHP have to do with it?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: If one doesn't know whether it can be achieved natively in SQL, then it might well have required application-layer logic...

Comment: @eggyal: Then the answer to _this_ question would be "you cannot do that" and he should post a new question tagged [tag:php] to ask specifically how to do it in that language.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: It *was* tagged [tag:php] until you removed it... :S

Comment: @eggyal: I _just_ explained why I removed it. Shall I explain it again?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Actually, you didn't.  You asked what PHP had to do with the question, then explained that if PHP was relevant to the question it should be posted again with the PHP tag.  Which is what the OP originally did.  Never mind: obviously PHP is *not* relevant to this question so this is all ridiculously hypothetical.

Comment: @eggyal: No, that's not at all what I said. I said "he should post a new question tagged [tag:php] to ask specifically how to do it in that language", which is a _different_ question, not "it should be posted again" which would be utterly pointless. My point is that, in general, questions tagged with more than one technology are _usually_ too broad and should be reformulated to be a concise question on a specific topic. As you indicate, though, it's moot here because I have been able to successfully make that edit myself in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just join your `temp_table` to the `states` and `cities` tables appropriately:

```sql
INSERT INTO original_table
  (id, state, city, address)
SELECT t.id, s.id, c.id, t.address
FROM   temp_table t
  JOIN states     s ON s.state_name = t.state
  JOIN cities     c ON c.city_name  = t.city
```

Comment: my temp_table contain state and city name in uppercase and state and city table contain inital letter in uppercase. this query will not match the state and city right. how can i do this?

Comment: @RakeshShetty: Use the typical, conventional methodology for case-insensitive comparison (hint: you can apply functions to fields named in the `ON` clause).

Comment: @RakeshShetty: Force a [case-insensitive collation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/case-sensitivity.html) using [`COLLATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/charset-collate.html).

Comment: sorry but can you explain me this in detail please

Comment: @RakeshShetty: What character encoding are those columns using?

Comment: hey @eggyal when i run your query it executed successfully how? Colloation is utf8_general_ci

Comment: @RakeshShetty: The trailing `_ci` means that collation is case insensitive.